# Generate 3D surface plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have a data frame which consists of 4 variables `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, I need to plot 3D surface plot for `x = A`, `y = B`, `z = C`. My problem is the plot should contain `3 surfaces` which is with respect to the values in `D` i.e `D` has values of `0`,`1` and `-1` I need to have 3 surfaces for 3 different values of `D`.

I tried by `sub setting` the data frame into 3 different dataframes with respect to the values of `D` and adding surface to `plot_ly` function but it doesnt seem to work and I am getting blank graph. I don't know if I am using the right plot function.

Below is my data frame `d1`

```
               A       B          C              D  
             734.5  2.28125     3.363312755      0    
             738    2.53125     3.395864326      0  
             727.25 2.484375    3.41183431       1
             737    2.421875    3.380499188      1
             727.25 2.3828125   3.39538442       1
             933.25 4.6875      3.148660474      1
             932.75 4.671875    3.155840809      1
             934    4.671875    3.165391107      1
             920.75 4.671875    3.194808475      1
             913.25 4.671875    3.22907393       1
             896.75 4.671875    3.287157844      1
             880    4.671875    3.341203642     -1
             866.75 4.59375     3.388017143     -1
             714.5  3.296875    3.572828317     -1
             730.75 3.296875    3.535364241     -1
             734.75 3.296875    3.526142314     -1
             713.25 3.7734375   3.653888449     -1
             711.75 3.8203125   3.665152882     -1
             711.75 3.8125      3.65967422      -1
             714    3.796875    3.630867839      0
             754.25 3.796875    3.560165628      0
             715.25 3.78125     3.650415301      0
```

Below is my R code

```
library(plotly)

pd1 <- subset(d1, (D == 1))
nd1 <- subset(d1, (D == -1))
zd1 <- subset(d1, (D == 0))  

p <-  plot_ly(showscale = FALSE) %>%
       add_surface(x= pd1$A,y = pd1$B, z = pd1$C)%>% 
        add_surface(x= nd1$A,y =nd1$B, z = nd1$C)%>% 
       add_surface(x= zd1$A,y =zd1$B, z = zd1$C)%>%
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to pass a numeric matrix as argument to `add_surface`.

```
pd1_ma <- as.matrix(pd1)
nd1_ma <- as.matrix(nd1)
zd1_ma <- as.matrix(zd1)


p <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE) %>%
  add_surface(z = ~pd1_ma) %>%
  add_surface(z = ~nd1_ma, opacity = 0.98) %>%
  add_surface(z = ~zd1_ma, opacity = 0.98)
p
```

That was working for me.